# Adjoint functors and exactness.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

If $F, G$ are adjoint functors between two abelian categories, then if $G$ is exact would that imply $F$ is also?

If not what assumptions need be made on $F$ or $G$ for this to hold?

Comment: Have you considered a single example? What about the hom-tensor adjunction?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, not since then this would imply all flat modules are projective.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: consider the forgetful functor from $\textrm{Mod-}R$ to the abelian groups.